# jQuery stops working on Postbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pageload

I have a page in asp.net which has a dropdown, now when user selects option from dropdown the page postbacks (PS:- I am not using UpdatePanel, neither planning to) the piece of jQuery stops working, initially it works, but after postbacks it stops working, i tried below code :

```
functioin pageLoad(){
  // my jQuery code here
}
```

also tried using `RegisterStartupScript` after dropdown item selection, but nothing works, tried googling but all the solutions are for UpdatePanel, also tried using

```
  var parameter = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    parameter.add_endRequest(function() {
        //jquery code again for working after postback
    });
```

could anyone suggests any option to make it work.
I am using DotNetNuke 7.4, if that would further help in suggestions.

Comment: does `//jquery code again for working after postback` get called

Comment: Yes it does goes inside it, and normal alerts works too, but when i initialize footable jquery it does not works, i am calling it like 
function pageLoad() { $('[id$=grid]').footable(); }

Comment: `$('[id$=grid]').footable();` see, the problem with jQuery is, there's no "error" if that selector finds zero elements - try `console.log($('[id$=grid]').length)` to see how many elements jQuery is going to run footable on

Comment: Yes it does gives length = 1 but still footable jquery initialization does not works

Comment: `does not works` - no errors though?

Comment: no, no errors..